# How to detect HTML code based on device on Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive

I have no experience in HTML and trying to make a small website for myself on WordPress.

I have the below custom code to play a video on my website:

```
<video poster="video poster link" controls="controls" width="270" height="490">
<source src="video link" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Video player displays perfectly in Desktop site. However, when WordPress resizes the website for tablets it does stretch a lot. So, I would like to change the sizing in code when it displays on tablets/mobile devices.

To detect I found following code online but I could not get it work:

```
<?php
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    /* Include/display resources targeted to phones/tablets here */
} else {
    /* Include/display resources targeted to laptops/desktops here */
}
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You'll want to use [CSS @media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have editing permissions on your code in your wordpress site, you could add a plugin like [fitvids](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fitvids-for-wordpress/). 
If you do have editing permissions, you can add a media query to check if the device width like so

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    video {
        max-width: 75%;
        height:auto;
}  // iPad

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    video {
        max-width: 45%;
        height:auto;
}  //Phone
```

Adjust width as necessary..

Hope this helps